# safest way to read missing dates with pandas read_csv--given blank space turns in today's date bug

Tags: python, pandas

py2.7
pandas version .13

What is the safest way to read a csv and convert the column to dates.
I noticed that in my case, a white space in the column of dates was converted to today's date.  Why?

here's my csv data

```
fake_file = StringIO.StringIO("""case,opdate,
7,10/18/2006,
7,10/18/2008,
621, ,""")
```

here's my code

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('path.csv',parse_dates=['opdate']))
```

tragically fills in the white space with today's date!

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('path.csv',parse_dates=['opdate'],na_values=' '))
```

works, but do i really have to know that it is always ' ', instead of say '' or 'null'.

What is the safest way to convert dates and keep the nulls (especially when the null isn't a consistent value)?

Comment: I usually read everything as string, then apply a helper function that includes try/except to convert each individual string. Or you can validate your strings with regex, and substitute all the values that aren't a date with ''.

Comment: That sounds good.  I'll work on a regex and post.  thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to pass a different date parser to [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) (I threw in a null too):

```
fake_file = StringIO.StringIO("""case,opdate,
7,null,
7,10/18/2008,
621, ,""")

In [11]: parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y', coerce=True)

In [12]: pd.read_csv(fake_file, parse_dates=['opdate'], date_parser=parser)
Out[12]:
   case     opdate  Unnamed: 2
0     7        NaT         NaN
1     7 2008-10-18         NaN
2   621        NaT         NaN

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Another option is to convert to dates after the fact using [to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html):

```
In [21]: df = pd.read_csv(fake_file)

In [22]: pd.to_datetime(df.opdate, format='%m/%d/%Y')
ValueError: time data 'null' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

In [23]: pd.to_datetime(df.opdate, format='%m/%d/%Y', coerce=True)
Out[23]:
0          NaT
1   2008-10-18
2          NaT
Name: opdate, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [24]: df['opdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.opdate, format='%m/%d/%Y', coerce=True)
```

*I think the fact that both `to_datetime` and `read_csv` convert blank/spaces to todays date is [**definitely** a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6428)...*

Answer (score 1):

You can specify NA values using the `na_values` argument to `read_csv`:

```
fake_file = StringIO.StringIO("""case,opdate,
7,10/18/2006,
7,10/18/2008,
621, ,""")

df = pd.read_csv(fake_file, parse_dates=[1], na_values={'opdate': ' '})
```

Output:

```
   case     opdate  Unnamed: 2
0     7 2006-10-18         NaN
1     7 2008-10-18         NaN
2   621        NaT         NaN
```

Comment: but i always need to know what those values will be, and if i get it wrong it will fill in today's date?